# How to create partition in ubuntu server 12.10

Tags: partition, ubuntu

I'm trying to create partition during Ubuntu Server installation(12.10).Now I have a 500GB hard disk where I need to create a partition of 200GB for root file system and another 20GB for swap space and the remaining 280GB logical partition called **backup** for storing backup files during upgradation .
I'm new to server installation,
How can I achieve the following:

1. I'm not familiar with RAID array partition and LVM partition. Which is better and how can I do partitioning using any of this.
2. How can I create a partition called **backup** and use this partition using command line.

Answer (score 1):

[RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) has nothing to do with [LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for), these are two different concepts, and for different purposes.

For the partition creation, you can do that during the installation guide (the partition part), no need to run command manually.

[Read the guide here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) and the links above should get you the basic ideas of partitioning.

Comment: LVM can be used to implement RAID. It supports stripping and mirroring.

Comment: One benefit of using LVM over hardware RAID is that the disk configuration is portable, you can move your disks to another server and as long as the kernel implements a modern version of LVM you can access your data. With hardware RAID, controllers die and your data may or may not ever get back online, usually the recovery or migration to another machine involves restoring from backups.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides a mechanism during install to allow you to resize partitions.

Here is a video explaining how to use it
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ

If you have already installed ubuntu, and want to resize the paritions without loosing data, then I highly recommend a gui tool if you are new to partitioning.

A good free partitioner is gparted

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

There are many tutorials on how to use gparted.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TK5YezY-Xc
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjQRkISnHQ4

You can create a live cd which contains gparted. Gparted will let you create, resize and delete partitions.

If you already have ubuntu installed, and you don't want to use a gui tool, then the utility to use is fdisk.  (assuming you aren't using lvm)

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/

Answer (score 0):

fdisk is a partition  tool.  Please take a look at "man fdisk".
  fdisk can solve your problem.

The latest version of lvm is lvm2. 
LVM2 has implemented software RAID.
   LVM is a logic volume tool.It can resize partition after you have finished partition.

Hardware RAID has better performance than software RAID(for example:lvm2).RAID support better formance,redundancy of data.

LVM2 support software RAID.LVM2 has more features than RAID.